# Function names syntax returned by radare2's afl?

Tags: radare2

Radare2's afl command returns function names with a specific syntax that I could not find documentation on:

For example:

```
radare2 -2 -A -q -c "aflj" C:/Windows/system32/advapi32.dll

0x77cce13c   22 280          sub.ntdll.dll_RtlNtStatusToDosError_13c
0x77cce259    7 62           fcn.77cce259
0x77cce29c   10 88           sub.KERNEL32.dll_lstrcmpiW_29c
0x77cce2f9   24 463          sub.KERNEL32.dll_lstrlenW_2f9
0x77c617b4    1 40           sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_LocalAlloc
0x77c6abe5    5 92   -> 130  sub.KERNEL32.dll_LocalAlloc_be5
0x77c7edd5    1 20           sub.KERNEL32.dll_LocalAlloc_dd5
```

- What is the meaning of the hexadecimal number after the function name ?
- Why is the core difference between the prefixes "sym." and "sub." of DLL function names ?
- What is the difference between library names in lower or uppercase ?

The DLL file names are all in lowercase:

- C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll

Comment: The last 3 hex digits are taken from the address. As for the capitalization: did you compare this with the names of those DLL's?

Comment: So, the 3 hex digits are taken from the address of what ? How is it possible to point to a DLL "sub.*" function "sub.*" which is not an exported symbole "sym.*" ? 

Is there a relation between sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_LocalAlloc and 
sub.KERNEL32.dll_LocalAlloc_be5 ?

Here are the file names, they are in lowercase:
 - "C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
 - "C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will start by answering your specific three questions, and then will shed more light about the naming structure of functions in radare2.

> What is the meaning of the hexadecimal number after the function name?

The meaning of the 3 hexadecimal digits at the end of function names like "sub.KERNEL32.dll_lstrlenW_2f9" are the last 3 digits of the function address. The confusion here is because this is not an imported function name, but a regular function. This naming caused by the `aan` command which you probably used when you executed `aaa` or opened a file with th `-A` flag: `$ r2 -A <filename>`.

As stated in the radare2 documentation:

```
...
aan                 autoname functions that either start with fcn.* or sym.func.*
...
```

The `aan` command will auto-generate a name, based on the flags being used in the function. This should ease the analysis for the user before analyzing the function.

So let's have a look at a function which is called `sub.KERNEL32.dll_DisableThreadLibraryCalls_18002a860`. You can see that an import function called "DisableThreadLibraryCalls" is being called. This is why the function was renamed by `aan`:

```
[0x18002a860]> pdf
╭ (fcn) sub.KERNEL32.dll_DisableThreadLibraryCalls_18002a860 35
│   sub.KERNEL32.dll_DisableThreadLibraryCalls_18002a860 ();
│           ; arg unsigned int arg3 @ rdx
│           0x18002a860      4883ec28       sub rsp, 0x28
│           0x18002a864      83fa01         cmp edx, 1
│       ╭─< 0x18002a867      7510           jne 0x18002a879
│       │   0x18002a869      48833dff1f00.  cmp qword [0x18002c870], 0 ; [0x18002c870:8]=0
│      ╭──< 0x18002a871      7506           jne 0x18002a879
│      ││   0x18002a873      ff159f170000   call qword sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_DisableThreadLibraryCalls 
│      ╰╰─> 0x18002a879      b801000000     mov eax, 1
│           0x18002a87e      4883c428       add rsp, 0x28
╰           0x18002a882      c3             ret
[0x18002a860]>
```

---

> Why is the core difference between the prefixes "sym." and "sub." of DLL function names?

`sym` stands for "Symbol". This is a symbol taken from the binary's [Symbol Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table).
`sub.` stands for "Subroutine". This can by a standalone function but most likely a part of a function, like JMPTABLE blocks, addresses in pointer table, etc.

---

> What is the difference between library names in lower or uppercase?

In general, radare2 keeps the case of the libraries as shown in the Import Address Tables. But I think sometimes it is being modified in favor of readability and to make it easier to differentiate between an import function, and a renamed function (`aan`).

---

### ASCII-ART Time

I made some ASCII-arts for you, hope this would make things clearer.

**Regular Function**

```
fcn.77cce259
|      |
|      |__ The function's address
|
|__ stands for "Function"
```

**Imported function**

```
sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_LocalAlloc
 |   |     |            |
 |   |     |            |__ The imported function name, "LocalAlloc"
 |   |     |
 |   |     |__ the Library name. In this case, "kernel32.dll"
 |   |
 |   |
 |   |___ "Import", this is an imported function
 |
 |___ "Symbol", taken from the Symbol Table
```

**Auto-Generated Name**

```
sub.ntdll.dll_RtlNtStatusToDosError_13c
 |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 |                   |
 |                   |__ auto-generated name based on flags that being used
 |                       the 3 digits at the end are the function's address
 |__ "Subroutine"
```

Comment: If I have well understood, the function sub.KERNEL32.dll_DisableThreadLibraryCalls_18002a860 is not strictly related to the import sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_DisableThreadLibraryCalls, except that the former might call the latter, along with possibly other imports.

Comment: Yes, exactly! This is the auto generated name based on an one Imported function that was used in this function.